The function sumAscii should take an array of names and calculate each name's score based on the total of each character's lowercase ASCII value
The function sumAscii should take an array of names and calculate each name's score based on the total of each character's lowercase ASCII value. It should return the name with the highest score. E.g. The name 'John' would get the score 431 because 'j' has the ASCII code 106, 'o' has the ASCII code 111, 'h' has the ASCII code 104 and 'n' has the ASCII code 110.
function sumAscii(arrayOfNames) {
  function getAsciiScore() {
    let sum = 0;
    let arrayOfAsciiCodes = [];
    for (const name of arrayOfNames) {
      name.split("").forEach((letter) => {
        sum += letter.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);
      });
    }
    return sum;
  }

  let highestScore = "";
  for (const name of arrayOfNames) {
    for (const letter of name) {
      return getAsciiScore(letter);
    }
  }
}

My function returns the total Ascii code score of all the names

Please [edit] your question to include sample input and actual expected output.

What is your question?  When using a debugger to step through the code, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

You're passing letter to getAsciiScore(), but that function doesn't have any parameters.

You're returning the score of the first letter; your nested for-loops never get past the first loop

Your code is almost ready. You just need to fix some logic errors:


function sumAscii(arrayOfNames) {
  function getAsciiScore(name) {
    let sum = 0;
    name.split("").forEach((letter) => {
        sum += letter.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);
    });
    return sum;
  }

  let highestScore = -1;
  let highestScoreName = null;
  for (const name of arrayOfNames) {
    let score = getAsciiScore(name);
    if (score > highestScore) {
      highestScore = score;
      highestScoreName = name;
    }
  }
  return highestScoreName;
}

console.log(sumAscii(["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]));



Here's a shorter method:


const sumAscii = (arrayOfNames) => {
    const getWordScore = (word) => [...word].reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0), 0);
    return arrayOfNames.sort((a, b) => getWordScore(b) - getWordScore(a))[0];
};

// Test
console.log(sumAscii(["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]));



But this is more inefficient than your code since it calculates each word's score multiple times. But this way is ok for small lists of small names.
This can be fixed with by storing the words with their score.


const sumAscii = (arrayOfNames) => {
    const getWordScore = (word) => [...word].reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0), 0);
    let combined = arrayOfNames.map(n => {return {name: n, score: getWordScore(n)}});
    return combined.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)[0].name;
};

// Test
console.log(sumAscii(["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]));



This is still less efficient, but the code is cleaner.

I just wanted to give it a shot and show another solution. I think you can use the map, reduce and Math.max function (the latter gives you the highest number in array). You can get the desired result as follow where I am returning an object with the index of the name with the highest sum, that name and the highest sum


let myArray = ['john', '123450', 'johnDoe',  '123', '12', '1']


function sumAscii(arrayOfNames) {
    let array2
       let SumArray = arrayOfNames.map(elem=>{
            let array1 =  Array.from(elem)
            return  array2 = array1.reduce((sum, letter)=>{return sum + letter.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0)}, 0)
        })
        let maxScore = Math.max(...SumArray)
        let wantedIndex = SumArray.indexOf(maxScore)
        return  {'index' : wantedIndex, 'name' : myArray[wantedIndex], 'maxscore': maxScore}
  }



  console.log(sumAscii(myArray))



